# Wierd behaviour while transfer of a file in pendrive

Tags: usb, filesystem, transfer

**HI** I have Ubuntu 20.04. When I transfer any file from laptop to Sandisk 16 GB pendrive greater than 800 mb or around it the 600-700 MB is transfered in 5 seconds and after that file transfer speed is around 1MB/sec and takes 30-40 seconds even if the transfer is completed. Is this normal ?

`Partitioning type` :- `Master Boot Record` [ I know that GPT is better but I have to use this pendrive for a old T.V and it doesn't detect devices with GPT partotioning scheme. ]

`Partition type` :- `W95 FAT32 (LBA)` <-- I don't know whats the meaning of it.

`Contents` :- `FAT (32-bit version)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't "weird" at all, but normal under most conditions. The slow-down will be seen for all large copies, though the point of slow-down will be different on every machine as this is largely based on available memory resources. System buffers are used during the copy process and will eventually flush to the target. This makes it rather difficult to consistently predict at what point a file copy will decelerate.

There are generally two ways to get around this slow-down:

1. Use a copy command that allows you to set your own buffers, such as `cpio` or `tar`.
2. Install the `nocache` package and use `nocache cp {source} {destination}`

If you are regularly working with very large file copies, the second option would be the simplest.

Comment: First :- How to use copy command can you please give me example?  Second :- Can you please give example of nocache also ? And is it safe ?@Matigo